# What the standardize method in answering an unsupport query type for DNS server

Tags: dns

I'm implementing a local dns server, without support some of the query types like CNAME/SRV/MX. I am wondering how to respond clients if they send such unsupport type of requests. Which rfc should I refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what you mean exactly by "don't support".

At least `CNAME` and `MX` are in the first official DNS specifications (RFC 1034 and 1035) so I guess it would be difficult for a server to claim being a DNS one without supporting them.

You can just treat them at any other type but claim they do not exist for the name request: that means returning NODATA (aka NOERROR + no answer content) if the name exists for other types, or NXDOMAIN if the name does not exist at all.

You can try also responding with `NOTIMPL` as return code, but that will confuse a lot of client.

It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve and also why you can't reuse an existing nameserver software.